# filtering dependency-track vulnerabilities notification

Tags: pebble

I have a dependency-track server that sends notifications to email for all new vulnerabilities.
I would like to send notifications only for critical vulnerabilities.
In the pebble templates, I would like to have something like this:

```
{% if subject.vulnerability.severity == "CRITICAL" %}
  // send notifications
{% else %}
  // do not send any notification
{% endif %}
```

Any idea?

I tried to use the template below, but it continues to send empty notifications also for those vulnerabilities with severity High, Medium and Minor.
In the else statement I should have something that invalidates the template.

```
{% if notification.group == "NEW_VULNERABILITY" %}
    {% if subject.vulnerability.severity == "CRITICAL" %}
        {{ notification.title }}

        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Vulnerability ID:  {{ subject.vulnerability.vulnId }}
        Severity:          {{ subject.vulnerability.severity }}
        Source:            {{ subject.vulnerability.source }}
        Component:         {{ subject.component.toString }}
        Component URL:     {{ baseUrl }}/component/?uuid={{ subject.component.uuid }}
        Project:           {{ subject.component.project.name }}
        Version:           {{ subject.component.project.version }}
        Description:       {{ subject.component.project.description }}
        Project URL:       {{ baseUrl }}/projects/{{ subject.component.project.uuid }}
        {% if  notification.subject.affectedProjects|length > 1%}
            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            Other affected projects:
            {% for affectedProject in notification.subject.affectedProjects %}
                {% if not (affectedProject.uuid == subject.component.project.uuid) %}
                    Project:[{{affectedProject.name}} : {{ affectedProject.version }}]
                    Project URL:{{ baseUrl }}/project/{{ affectedProject.uuid }}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        {{ notification.content }}

        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        {{ timestamp }}

    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found your answer already, you should be able to achieve this through the policy violations.

Add a policy configuration to detect components with critical vulnerabilities.

[image: DependencyTrack policy configuration]

You can then configure your notifications based on policy violations.